# SVG how to center arbitrary picture?

Tags: svg

I have an SVG with a map whose coordinates are arbitrary, e.g. it can have positive OR negative X and Y values. Best way to think about this is to place yourself in the middle of a room and everything left of you is negative X and everything behind you is negative y.

I would like to draw these coordinates as Rects and then center the whole bunch on the screen.
What I am struggling with is positioning the Rects always to the center of the screen.
Currently I am doing it like this:

```
const cleanedPoints = [{"type": 2, "x": 128, "y": -128}, {"type": 2, "x": 128, "y": -129}, {"type": 2, "x": 128, "y": -127}, ... ]
const viewBoxSizeX = maxX - minX + minX / 4;
const viewBoxSizeY =  Math.abs(minY) - Math.abs(maxY) + Math.abs(minY / 4);
const minX =  minX - minX / 4;
const minY =  minY - Math.abs(minY / 4);
const viewBox = `${minX} ${minY} ${viewBoxSizeX} ${viewBoxSizeY}`;

<Svg
    style={{ borderColor: borderColor, borderWidth: 1 }}
    height={'100%'}
    width={'100%'}
    viewBox={viewBox}
    preserveAspectRatio={'xMidYMid meet'}>
    <G>
        {cleanedPoints.length > 0 &&
            cleanedPoints.map((point, index) => {
                return (
                    <Rect
                        key={index}
                        x={point.x}
                        y={point.y}
                        stroke={COLORS.primaryLight}
                        width={'0.5'}
                        height={'0.5'}
                        fill={COLORS.primaryLight}
                    />
                );
            })}
        
    </G>
</Svg>
```

As you can see this is not really centered
[image: Error]

Comment: You will first need to get the center of group of shapes using getBBox(). Then you will need to change the value of the viewBox attribute so that the group of shapes falls in the center of the svg canvas

Comment: Thanks, will take a look - let'sd hope react-native-svg has a getBBox or similar